# Loading data from a file and converting into an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am trying to load the data from a file. There are 3 rows and columns and I want to convert into an array `A` with shape `(3,3)`. How do I go about doing it?

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('A.csv')[:, 0]
```

The data looks like

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to8Ep.png)

The array `A` should be

```
A=np.array([[0.751900795,0.720029442,0.519947357],
[0.757660601,0.682370477,0.693973342],
[0.799340382,0.641430593,0.73287523]])
```

Comment: Since there seems to be empty rows in your csv file, maybe try converting the file to a panda dataframe first to get rid of the empty rows. Then convert the resulting dataframe to numpy.

Comment: You are going to load a text file, so you need to use a mix of string's split to get each value to convert to integer; then you can fill your array.
Go to the official python API website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, convert the file to a panda dataframe first to get rid of the empty rows in your dataset. Then convert the resulting dataframe to numpy.

#### data.csv

```
0.751900795,0.720029442,0.519947357

0.757660601,0.682370477,0.693973342

0.799340382,0.641430593,0.73287523
```

#### code

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
s = df. to_numpy()
print(s)
```

#### output

```
[[0.75190079 0.72002944 0.51994736]
 [0.7576606  0.68237048 0.69397334]
 [0.79934038 0.64143059 0.73287523]]
```